# Adding Dynamic Timers to Google Map Arrow Markers

Tags: jquery

I've created a Google Map with arrows representing different phases of a road intersection. These arrows are generated using SVG coordinates and adjusted to align with the road. Now, I want to integrate dynamic timers with jQuery to show the countdown in seconds until the traffic signal changes. Can you provide guidance on how to achieve this?

This is just mock what I want to achieve

[image: This is just mock what I want to achieve]

I have written the following code which successful draws the arrows but timer part is still incomplete

[![I have written the following code which successful draws the arrows but timer part is still incomplete][2]][2]

var svg_2xbrightred = "M 38.566406 0.328125 C 38.28125 0.402344 37.636719 0.757812 37.144531 1.117188 C 36.652344 1.460938 28.578125 8.9375 19.207031 17.710938 C 3.0625 32.832031 2.136719 33.726562 1.675781 34.664062 C 1.179688 35.632812 1.164062 35.679688 1.34375 36.511719 C 1.507812 37.242188 1.628906 37.449219 2.136719 37.867188 C 3.46875 38.941406 2.691406 38.882812 16.710938 38.882812 L 29.296875 38.882812 L 29.296875 81.886719 C 29.296875 129.097656 29.238281 125.910156 30.195312 127.933594 C 31.046875 129.753906 32.480469 131.183594 34.304688 132.0625 C 35.917969 132.820312 36.578125 132.910156 40.433594 132.851562 C 43.542969 132.804688 43.960938 132.777344 44.753906 132.464844 C 47.429688 131.464844 49.371094 129.425781 50.328125 126.625 C 50.582031 125.835938 50.597656 124.152344 50.644531 82.335938 L 50.671875 38.882812 L 63.304688 38.882812 C 77.324219 38.882812 76.515625 38.941406 77.816406 37.882812 C 78.339844 37.464844 78.460938 37.257812 78.625 36.527344 C 78.804688 35.664062 78.789062 35.632812 78.296875 34.664062 C 77.816406 33.710938 76.921875 32.847656 60.761719 17.710938 C 51.390625 8.921875 43.453125 1.519531 43.125 1.25 C 41.867188 0.238281 40.121094 -0.121094 38.566406 0.328125 Z M 38.566406 0.328125";
var svgLeftArrow = "M 35.246094 0.640625 C 34.273438 1.101562 33.648438 1.742188 18.3125 17.875 C 9.535156 27.097656 2.003906 35.113281 1.554688 35.691406 C 0.597656 36.929688 0.238281 37.972656 0.328125 39.179688 C 0.433594 40.667969 0.910156 41.382812 3.828125 44.46875 C 5.292969 46.015625 12.75 53.851562 20.375 61.898438 C 33.976562 76.199219 34.273438 76.511719 35.292969 76.988281 C 36.308594 77.464844 36.367188 77.480469 37.144531 77.300781 C 38.175781 77.078125 38.894531 76.375 39.3125 75.171875 C 39.597656 74.304688 39.613281 73.964844 39.613281 61.941406 L 39.613281 49.605469 L 58.59375 49.605469 L 58.625 87.699219 L 58.667969 125.804688 L 59.101562 127.054688 C 60.195312 130.167969 62.765625 132.300781 66.128906 132.894531 C 66.785156 133 68.148438 133.042969 70 132.984375 C 72.453125 132.925781 73.019531 132.867188 73.839844 132.582031 C 75.261719 132.105469 76.308594 131.464844 77.355469 130.4375 C 78.355469 129.441406 79.011719 128.398438 79.550781 126.921875 L 79.894531 125.953125 L 79.941406 80.996094 C 79.984375 31.253906 80.058594 35.15625 79 33.085938 C 78.011719 31.105469 76.070312 29.464844 73.839844 28.707031 L 72.871094 28.378906 L 56.25 28.335938 L 39.613281 28.289062 L 39.613281 15.804688 C 39.613281 3.648438 39.597656 3.308594 39.3125 2.441406 C 38.894531 1.265625 38.148438 0.507812 37.191406 0.296875 C 36.261719 0.105469 36.414062 0.0742188 35.246094 0.640625 Z M 35.246094 0.640625";

```
        //Showing the markers from Map.xml file 
        for (index = 0; index < mapFileMarkers.length; index++) {

            var startLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mapFileMarkers[index].laneEndLatitude, mapFileMarkers[index].laneEndLongitude);
            var endLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mapFileMarkers[index].laneStartLatitude, mapFileMarkers[index].laneStartLongitude);

            // Calculate the degree of Arrow based on the lane direction 
            var rotationDegree = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(startLatLng, endLatLng);

            //Dafault image is straight arrow 
            var iconImage = svg_2xbrightred;

            // if lane phase is 1,3,5 or 7 thats means it should show left arrow  
            const leftLanePhases = ["1", "3", "5", "7"];
            if (leftLanePhases.includes(mapFileMarkers[index].lanePhase)) {
                iconImage = svgLeftArrow;
            }

            //Creating a icon that is being displayed as the arrow for different lanes and phases
            const icon = {
                path: iconImage,
                fillColor: "grey",
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                rotation: rotationDegree,// Marker rotation based on the lane direction
                scale: 0.35,
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 100), // origin
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
            };
```